# Why are subject lines hyperlinks

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

I wanted to copy a string from a question's subject line to my clipboard.

When I hover over the subject, it is a hyperlink to the current page.  This makes it challenging to highlight text and copy it.

And what's the possible use of making the subject line into a hyperlink to the page I'm already on?

I am suggesting that the subject line just be plain text.

Comment: You *can* copy the text if you hover just a bit before the text begins.

Comment: Yes, but then you are forced to start at either the beginning or end of the subject, and not somewhere in the middle.

Comment: If you want to highlight from the middle, start a little above or below the text.

Comment: I only said it was challenging.  Not impossible.   : )   And I still don't see the value of making the subject a hyperlink in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for finding the duplicate, my search didn't turn it up.  Probably because I call it a "subject" rather than a "title".